# Nativescript vue slot default component issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I was trying to create an mobile application with nativescript-vue and faced a problem with default component rendering while using slots.
So there is App.vue with Frame and inner slot.

```
<Frame ~mainContent>
  <slot name="mainContent"></slot>
</Frame>
```

Also there is a router with available components:

```
import EducationPlacesList from './components/EducationPlacesList'
import PersonalProfile from './components/PersonalProfile'

const router = {
   EducationPlacesList: EducationPlacesList,
   PersonalProfile: PersonalProfile
}
```

And as Vue router is currently not supported for nativescript vue there is a solution for navigating through manual routing and it works just fine. I have a sidebar with labels and `ontap` there is a
`this.$navigateTo(this.$router[to], options)` - which perfectly redirects me by tapping.

But if i start my application and do not tap any of links there will be an empty space as expected. Because slot is empty until navigation to some page. I wonder, is there a good practice, how to set the default component for this slot.

Comment: I'm not sure why you even need slot here, by default you must render a Page on Frame and you could pass the Page component instead of slot. When user clicks on any link, you may navigate on the frame which will replace current page.

Comment: @Manoj, I misunderstood the example. Thought the binding of the page was to the slot.name.. Thanks a lot, you've just opened my eyes. Now its all working.